# Is there a way to "scry" across planes to the Nine Hells?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm not necessarily requiring the *scrying* spell (because it is limited to the plane you're on), but is it possible to get a similar effect of seeing/hearing through a sensor/creature/something else on another plane?

The goal is to send a creature to the Nine Hells and verify what's on the other side without risking the life of a humanoid.

I am looking for solutions that are standard options in the rulebooks and not requesting homebrew or houserule solutions.

Comment: Is a chance of failure OK, or does it need to be a lead pipe cinch?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'll take a chance of failure, but I'd prefer a lead pipe cinch :)

Comment: @NautArch: You should ask about the problem you have, rather than asking a broader question that might not end up getting an answer the question you actually want answered. If someone else wants a broader answer, they can ask the broader question themselves... Otherwise, you might end up having to ask the more specific question yourself as a separate question. (Related: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 8):

### Literally See a Place in Another Plane

Casing *beast sense* on a familiar or other willing beast and sending it to the target plane would allow the caster to perceive the destination in another plane.

### Get Information About a Place in Another Plane

#### Ask a Planar Ally

Negotiating with a creature to act as a spy via *[planar ally](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Planar%20Ally#content)* is a viable option.  The spell description explicitly lists "spy on our enemies" as something that one might request.

#### Sending on an Intelligent Familiar or Ally

Having a familiar go to the plane and then cast *[sending](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sending#content)* on it is a method to get some information about the destination without risking a humanoid.

> You can send the message across any distance and even to other planes
>   of existence, but if the target is on a different plane than you,
>   there is a  percent chance that the message doesn’t arrive. (PHB, Sending spell; description)

#### Ask a Deity

If the information your seeking is sufficiently specific that it can be obtained with a yes or no answer, using *[commune](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Commune#content)* to ask your divine power may work.

#### Contact Other Plane

Another ask an extra planar entity could potentially obtain the information by means of the *contact other plane* spell.

Comment: How does one communicate with this Planar Ally once it's on a different plane?

Comment: @NautArch ostensibly the caster would petition for assistance that has some capability for that.  I would expect a number of celestial or devils have such capability.

Comment: The sending stones is a great idea!

Comment: The question has been edited to be more specific; you should make sure the answer still fits, and potentially edit it to be more specific as well.

Comment: Familiar is not a  beast, so Beast Sense wouldn't work on it.

Answer (score 3):

This only meets part of your requirements, since it does put a humanoid in the line of fire (though it doesn't have to be a friendly humanoid).

It's maybe not RAI, but a Warlock with the *Gaze of Two Minds* Eldritch Invocation can see through the eyes of a creature on another plane for a single round.

> You can use your action to touch a willing humanoid and perceive through its senses until the end of your next turn.

The restriction on seeing across planes is only on the renewal clause:

> As long as the creature is on the same plane of existence as you, you can use your action on subsequent turns to maintain this connection...

You have to do the following:

1. Gaze through the eyes of a humanoid on your turn
2. Send the humanoid to the plane of your choosing using *Gate* or whatever on their turn.
3. See through their eyes until your next turn.

You can get a little more out of this by using a Fighter as the humanoid you are looking through, and having them Action Surge to get an action on the far side of the portal.

Comment: I'd prefer if a humanoid wasn't sacrificed. As they may not be able to get back, or the destination is bad news bears, a suicide mission isn't quite what I'm hoping for. I've added that requirement to the question.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with. Is there a type of creature that would be an acceptable loss?

Comment: Possibly a Beast or Undead. Leaning more heavily towards Undead.

Comment: So using a 'disposable' humanoid like a kobold or goblin is out?

Comment: Ouch! Yeah, I think so. Don't really have disposable humanoids where we are right now. And not sure a disposable humanoid would accept this job, either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78539/discussion-between-nautarch-and-a-very-large-bear).

Comment: The question has been edited to be more specific; you should make sure the answer still fits, and potentially edit it to be more specific as well.